# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dfr'

Tags: python

I have a following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dfr'`

```
import tethne.readers as rd
wordcounts = rd.dfr.ngrams(datapath, N='uni')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dfr'
```

rd?  shows the document about the attributes of the packages including dfr.

I moved the package called tethne from python3.7 package directory to the site-pakages directory and used conda env2.7.(since this package is compatible with python 2, not python3) This may cause this error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install module `tethne`?

Comment: I activate 2.7 and pip install the package again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from tethne.readers import dfr
```

Comment: This is similar. For the second method, it produces : ImportError: cannot import name drf .  For the first one, it says: from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin, urldefrag, ImportError: No module named parse. This occurs even though I can import urllib.(I can't use the attribute,  urllib.parse, somehow)

Comment: Which [version of Python](http://pythonhosted.org/tethne/install.html#python) are you using?

Comment: I use python 2.7(conda) for this one

Comment: There was a typo in my second line (*drf* instead of `dfr`). I corrected it.